# Black lip appearing when resizing web browser for responsive design

Tags: responsive-design

Dear stackoverflow community,

I recently upgraded my PC after using original unit for some 12yrs with windows 7.

I am now running win11 pro, with 16GB of RAM and have a 4GB graphics card. I have noticed when resizing IE Edge, chrome or opera browser a black lip appearing around bottom-right edge of window as per screenshot below. Funnily enough the behaviour is not apparent when using FF.

I consulted the manufacturer of PC and they advised ensuring the monitor was interfaced with graphics card with latest drivers; which it is.

I also found this thread on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows11/comments/xbtvkn/the_microsoft_edge_app_window_has_a_black_border/. The poster (logicearth) seems to be suggesting this is normal behaviour and the black patch appears to conserve system resources; as opposed to writing immediately to screen.

I know I don't have the best spec of computer, but it certainly isn't the worst..can anyone advise if this is normal behaviour as I habitually resize browsers when developing responsive websites and would prefer the absence of black lip if possible?

Robert[image: black lip bottom-right of browser]